# Power BI - M Code - New column that returns the earliest date for a specific value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've got a large table with the following fields, among many others:

- AccountID
- ApprovalDate

AccountIDs appear numerous times in the table, with unique ApprovalDate values.

I'd like to create a new column that returns the earliest ApprovalDate for the AccountID. I can handle this at the PBI visual level and in the PBI table using DAX, but I'm having trouble implementing this in M Code.

I've attempted to use a combination of List.First and List.Generate, but I'm either inputting incorrect syntax or simply timing out.

Comment: Create a new table grouped by AccountID with min(ApprovalDate).  Then join that to your table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Mcode

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data06may23.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"AccountID", Int64.Type}, {"ApprovalDate", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"AccountID"}, {{"ApprovalDate", each List.Min([ApprovalDate]), type nullable date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```